# When query two sheets, how to make any new row in both sheets stack at the bottom of the entire sheet instead of in the middle

Tags: google-sheets

I have some ID in both Sheet1 and Sheet2, and new ID is added in the bottom of each sheet.
Then I use query function to combine these two sheets into Sheet3 with this function:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({'Sheet1'!A:A; 'Sheet2'!A:A},"where Col1 <>''"))
```

Now I have the ID combination of Sheet1 and Sheet2 in Sheet3, and I hope to make the newly added ID from both Sheet1 and Sheet2 appear in the bottom of the Sheet3. (As we all know, normally the newly added ID in Sheet1 appears in the middle row of the ID combination.)

Is this feasible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to solve this you would need to add timestamps to your dataset or do it like this:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({'Sheet1'!A1:A10; 'Sheet2'!A:A; 'Sheet1'!A11:A}, "where Col1 <>''"))
```

where A1:A10 is existing data and A11:A will be new data - tho this is not versatile at all so here is a script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() =="Sheet1" ) {                   //1st sheet
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) {                       //monitor column A
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);                 //print timestamp in column B
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");               //format of the timestamp
  nextCell.setValue(newDate);
}}
if( s.getName() =="Sheet2" ) {                   //2nd sheet
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) {                       //monitor column A
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);                 //print timestamp in column B
  var newDate1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");               //format of the timestamp
  nextCell.setValue(newDate1);
}}}
```

and then your formula will be:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({Sheet1!A:B; Sheet2!A:B}, 
 "select Col1 where Col1 <>'' order by Col2", 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of adding timestamp. As I can probably add timestamp in my raw data, I think I'm able to make it without the script. Thanks!